# Maven build failed in xsd pattern validation

Tags: java, regex, maven, xsd, java-7

I have a pattern: `(?!^0000000000000000000)([0-9]{20})` that should validate all numbers with length `= 20` excluding `0000000000000000000`

I was write unit test:

```
 String pattern = "(?!^0000000000000000000)([0-9]{20})";
 String input  = "0000000000000000000";
 String input1 = "0000000000000000000123123";
 String input2 = "123123"
 String input3 = "1231231244245343604";
 Assert.assertFalse(input.matches(pattern))
 Assert.assertFalse(input1.matches(pattern))
 Assert.assertFalse(input2.matches(pattern))
 Assert.assertTrue(input3.matches(pattern))
```

This code works well, but when I try to build my project using maven with pattern in xsd it fails with validation pattern error
What I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the pattern in XSD where XSD regex syntax is in place? You can't use lookarounds there, as well as `^` and `$` anchors.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so how i need to modify my regular expression?

Comment: One way is to spell out the alternatives: `[0-9]{19}[1-9]|[0-9]{18}[1-9][0-9]|...`

Comment: always helpful: https://regex101.com/

Comment: @fl0w Not always, regex101 does not support XSD regex syntax.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew true that, mea culpa :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the following restriction :

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedLong">
    <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
    <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{20}"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

This makes sure your input is a positive 20-digits number that is greater than `00000000000000000000`.

If you need your type to be based on a string, you'll have to spell out all the possible alternatives in a pattern as [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/) suggested :

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{19}[1-9]|[0-9]{18}[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]{17}[1-9][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{16}[1-9][0-9]{3}|[0-9]{15}[1-9][0-9]{4}|[0-9]{14}[1-9][0-9]{5}|[0-9]{13}[1-9][0-9]{6}|[0-9]{12}[1-9][0-9]{7}|[0-9]{11}[1-9][0-9]{8}|[0-9]{10}[1-9][0-9]{9}|[0-9]{10}[1-9][0-9]{9}|[0-9]{9}[1-9][0-9]{10}|[0-9]{8}[1-9][0-9]{11}|[0-9]{7}[1-9][0-9]{12}|[0-9]{6}[1-9][0-9]{13}|[0-9]{5}[1-9][0-9]{14}|[0-9]{4}[1-9][0-9]{15}|[0-9]{3}[1-9][0-9]{16}|[0-9]{2}[1-9][0-9]{17}|[0-9][1-9][0-9]{18}"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

Comment: in my case its string not long

Comment: @Anton I've updated my answer to include Wiktor's suggestion as a solution to apply restrictions to an `xs:string`, but I suggest you give a good consideration to the use of `xs:unsignedLong` ;)